# How does the MSBuild:Compile generator work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to use the MSBuild:Compile generator to trigger a compilation of my custom file type when the file is saved in Visual Studio (should work like a custom tool but with msbuild). The build process itself is working but it doesn't seem to be triggered if the file is saved.

Can someone explain what exactly the MSBuild:Compile entry is doing? As far I have just seen this used in the antlr msbuild scripts and for XAML.

Below I have an extract of the msbuild setup I use to compile a *.myext file to a *.g.ts file.

---

My targets file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="SampleNamespace.CustomCompilerTask" AssemblyFile="MyTask.dll" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
            CustomLayoutCompile;
            $(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)
        </PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <CustomTypeCompile>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </CustomTypeCompile>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>

    <Target Name="CustomLayoutCompile" Inputs="@(TypeScriptCompile);@(CustomTypeCompile)" Outputs="@(CustomTypeCompile->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).g.ts')">
        <CustomCompilerTask TypeScriptFiles="@(TypeScriptCompile)" LayoutFiles="@(CustomTypeCompile)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

---

Entries in the project file:

```
....

<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="MyControl.ts">
      <DependentUpon>MyControl.myext</DependentUpon>
    </TypeScriptCompile>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="MyControl.g.ts">
      <DependentUpon>MyControl.myext</DependentUpon>
    </TypeScriptCompile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <CustomTypeCompile Include="MyControl.myext">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </CustomTypeCompile>
</ItemGroup>
....

<Import Project="path/to/my/target/file/mytargets.targets" />

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2019 and was suffering from the same exact issue. I finally figured out a workaround, which make the issue looks more like a VisualStudio/MSBuild bug to me. My workaround is that when you define your `ItemDefinitionGroup`, define a custom/extended file property page like below.  It worked for me. Hope it also works for everyone else too.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)CustomPerperties.CSharp.xml">
        <Context>File;BrowseObject</Context>
    </PropertyPageSchema>
    <AvailableItemName Include="CustomTypeCompile" />
</ItemGroup>
```